# Комедогенное или комедоногенное действие

Tags: общие-вопросы

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться: комедогенное или комедоногенное действие.

Answer (score 1):

Комедоны (белые угри, черные угри)  - это вид кисты, образующейся при закупорке устья волосяного фолликула различными массами.  Корень "ген"  - от греч. «генос» – рождение.  Соответственно, комедогенный и  комедоногенный - это рождающий комедоны.

Из этих двух вариантов чаще встречается "комедогенный" с усеченной основой, что связано, скорее всего, с более удобной фонетической формой.

Кроме повышенной жирности кожи, причиной появления комедонов может быть неправильно подобранная косметика. Некоторые фирмы размещают на своих упаковках надпись non-comedogenic.